# Decoding docker error log from Eventviewer

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I did the setup docker on a Windows server 2016 VM. We have docker Dev,Test and Prod environments and recently we observed some weird error in Prod.

The output from docker info is listed below.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 4
Server Version: 17.06.2-ee-15
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.2551.amd64fre.rs1_release.181004-1309)
Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Standard
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.704GiB
Name: ntprnch01
ID: F2WP:CY45:XBIU:3FE4:BUBS:Z467:SVQ7:3HZB:GUB5:KWWJ:7H2Y:FFLA
Docker Root Dir: D:\docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Http Proxy: http://proxydetails [Edited]
Https Proxy: http://proxydetails [Edited]
No Proxy: Noproxy List[Edited]
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 Provaterepo.company:9000
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

I am yet to run any containers in this particular box.
But I downloaded few docker images. I did the docker setup couple of weeks back and today when I was going through the event logs, I was surprised to see few docker errors.

Wondering what might be causing these errors in eventlogs. But yes when I tried to import new images now, no error is logged.
These errors keep recurring. The overall content remains same but container id keeps changing.

The error is

```
The description for Event ID 1 from source docker cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Handler for POST /v1.24/containers/bca4617b67f1e227ccc702b9b097586f68470abae258b653dfd1a7bd1c1d270d/kill returned error: Cannot kill container bca4617b67f1e227ccc702b9b097586f68470abae258b653dfd1a7bd1c1d270d: Container bca4617b67f1e227ccc702b9b097586f68470abae258b653dfd1a7bd1c1d270d is not running
```

Comment: Restarting is always worth to have a shot.

Comment: Yes that's what we do now. The issue is recurring and these kind of errors is no good in prod environment.